# Split container with three panels

Tags: c#, winforms, split, containers, panel

I have an interesting little problem. I'm using a one parent split container on the main form and multiple panels. I dropped three panels in the container. Two of them on the top (panel 1) and one on the bottom (panel 2). The problem I'm having is the two on the top in panel 1. Trying to work with the two panels on the top I'm using the properties to select them. Although the properties appears to select the panel, it does not bring it to the front in the designer so that I can work on it

Does anyone have an idea how to work with panels so that they can be selected and design?

Do I need to use a split container for each panel? I sure hope not. :-(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, C# forms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the document viewer is the place to go. Under View, Other Windows, Document Outline (Ctrl+Alt+T). The Treeview may be expanded so just locate the split container and collapse the panels. Simply drag-and-drop the panel that you need to view directly under the split container panel (in my case splitContainer.panel1). Now the panel should be in focus and viewed. Oh, one more thing. Make sure the panels are docked.

That should do it... :)